# Exporting .CSV column data as unique row into separate file then sort

Tags: powershell

Using the below script, how can I extract the unique column data which is in IPAddress format and then save it as ColumnName.TXT?

```
$ColumnNames = @('client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip')
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs\Input\ -Filter *.csv |
    Get-Content |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Split(',')[$ColumnNames] } |
            Sort-Object -Unique | Sort -asc |
                Set-Content -Path C:\LOGS\Unique-$($ColumnNames).txt
```

It is not working for the.CSV file with the double-quotes.

Somehow the MessageTraceDetails.CSV file that I downloaded from Microsoft 365 portal will always have the header like below:

`"date_time_utc","client_ip","client_hostname","server_ip","server_hostname","source_context","connector_id","source","event_id","internal_message_id","message_id","network_message_id","recipient_address","recipient_status","total_bytes","recipient_count","related_recipient_address","reference","message_subject","sender_address","return_path","message_info","directionality","tenant_id","original_client_ip","original_server_ip","custom_data"`

Would it be possible to remove all double quote from the .CSV file and then perform the search?

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with just one input CSV file, this would do:

```
$ColumnNames = 'client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip'
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Logs\Input\TheInputFile.csv'

# get the headers as they are found in this CSV file
$headers = $data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name

foreach ($column in $ColumnNames) {
    # test if a column name from the array can be found in the CSV
    # and if so, output a new file with the values of that column
    if ($headers -contains $column) {
        $file = Join-Path -Path 'D:\Test' -ChildPath ('Unique-{0}.txt' -f $column)
        Set-Content -Path $file -Value ($data.$column | Sort-Object -Unique)
    }
}
```

However, if there are more csv files in the folder to process, I think you need to prepend the output files with the basename of the original csv file aswell, in order not to overwrite the output again and again.

```
$ColumnNames = 'client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Logs\Input' -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object { 
    $data = Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName
    # get the headers as they are found in this CSV file
    $headers = $data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name

    foreach ($column in $ColumnNames) {
        # test if a column name from the array can be found in the CSV
        # and if so, output a new file with the values of that column
        if ($headers -contains $column) {
            $file = Join-Path -Path 'C:\LOGS' -ChildPath ('{0}_Unique-{1}.txt' -f $_.BaseName, $column)
            Set-Content -Path $file -Value ($data.$column | Sort-Object -Unique )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, however, I got no result in the Output directory, but lots of Original.csv-COlumnName.CSV with 0 KB ?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Then are the ColumnNames as you describe in the array actually used in any of these cvs files? Do they have headers?

Comment: This is the header name:
'client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip'

Comment: and also there are others.CSV files in the source directory that does not have IP address or the column name 'client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip'

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer The csv files as mentioned in your last comment should account for the empty output files.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I have updated my answer to create output files only if a column with the name from the `$ColumnNames` array actually exists in the imported CSV

Comment: that's great, so far it is only failed when the .CSV file content is in Double Quote like "209.85.167.53" for one of the IP address example ?

Comment: The column name is also enclosed in the double quote as well.
like: "date_time_utc","client_ip","client_hostname","server_ip","server_hostname", ....

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Double-quotes should not be a problem, unless they are doubled (`""date_time_utc""`) or contain whitespace characters. Are you sure all csv files use the comma as delimiter? Can you edit your question and post the first 3 or 4 lines of such a failing csv file? (open with Notepad then copy/paste so I can see the actual raw data)

Comment: there are multiple CSV files in the directory and not all of them have all the column name like in $columnNames.

Comment: I've uploaded the header format of one of the .CSV file.
the content is double quotes as well.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I cannot reproduce any failure.. Using your example works just fine because Import-Csv **strips** the quotes from the headers and values. There must be something else wrong with some of the csv files. What exacly fails at your end?

Comment: Very strange :-| because when I open the MTDetails.CSV fresh from Microsoft 365 portal with excel and then save it, the double quote is gone. Hence the script is working.
However, when the.CSV is freshly downloaded not opened, the script failed to detect the column name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1)

```bsh
# Import the CSV
$Csv = Import-CSV -Path "Path to your CSV file"

# Collect the header names.
$Columns = ($Csv |  Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }).Name

# Loop through the columns.
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
    # Set the file content based off Unique strings.
    $Csv.$Column | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path "C:\LOGS\Unique-$Column.txt"
}
```

I removed the part where I think you've attempted to sort the IP addresses in ascending order. There's a couple of reasons for this.

- Firstly, [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-5.1) does not have an `-Ascending` parameter. This is default behaviour
- Secondly, it won't work the way you want it to as you have string values. 10 will appear before 2.

If you would like to sort them, then you can use a trick using [`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.1) to sort them properly.

```bsh
[string[]]$IPArray = [System.Version[]]($Csv.$Column) | Sort-Object -Unique
```

This would change the original script to.

```bsh
# Import the CSV
$Csv = Import-CSV -Path "Path to your CSV file"

# Collect the header names.
$Columns = ($Csv |  Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }).Name

# Loop through the columns.
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
    # Set the file content based off Unique strings and use System.Version to sort the addresses.
    [string[]]$IPArray = [System.Version[]]($Csv.$Column) | Sort-Object -Unique
    $IPArray | Set-Content -Path "C:\LOGS\Unique-$Column.txt"
}
```

If necessary loop through multiple CSV files updating the path location, you may want to reference the CSV name in the file name when setting it to differentiate between the output files. For example.

```bsh
$Csvs = Get-ChildItem "Path to csv files"
foreach ($Csv in $Csvs) {
    $Csv = Import-CSV -Path $Csv.Fullname

    # code above with change for setting content.
    ... | Set-Content -Path "C:\LOGS\Unique-$($Csv.Basename)-$Column.txt"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ash, thank for the reply, where do I specify the column name with the IP address content?

Comment: This will take all the columns from the CSV file if they are all just IP string columns. If they aren't, then replace the `$Columns` line as so: `$Columns = @('client_ip', 'server_ip', 'original_client_ip', 'original_server_ip')` or with the names of your actual columns.